# PHP/Mysql - Add form data HTML elements with line breaks

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, str-replace, stripslashes

Basically, I have an administration area where users are to be able to add information to a MySQL database using a form textarea.  The users have little or no HTML knowledge so I'd like them to be able to use their return key to create line breaks instead of `<br />` tags, however I also want the use of HTML to be permitted too for future purposes.  I also won't want `<br />` tags to appear in the textarea after insertion and would like line breaks instead so as not to confuse people - basically display it in the textarea exactly as it was entered.

I've been having difficulty parsing the data though, I've come up with a solution to prevent the line breaks from being stripped but I just really want to know if this is valid - it works, but if I've learned anything recently I know that doesn't mean it's right!

```
$extra_details_escape = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['extra_details']);
$extra_details_escape = str_replace('\r\n','LiNeBrEaK',$extra_details_escape);
$extra_details_escape = stripslashes($extra_details_escape);
$extra_details_escape = str_replace('LiNeBrEaK','\r\n',$extra_details_escape);
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET column = '$extra_details_escape' WHERE id = '$id'");
```

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: a standard textarea will not create `<br>` tags for newlines, so are you using an WYSIWYG editor of sorts?

Comment: Hi Lawrence.  It doesn't add <br> tags itself, I just mentioned that I didn't want them in there to rule out nl2br as an option as I want to maintain them as \r\n

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried nl2br() ?

Try this, post string sanitization:

```
$extra_details_escape = nl2br($_POST['extra_details']);
```

Comment: Hi Darius, I don't want any `<br />` tags involved at all on this side as I perform nl2br when the data is retrieved elsewhere.